# Why I can see two enabled python versions in my pyenv versions command result?

Tags: pyenv

Hi I see two enabled versions in my `pyenv versions` result. Why is that, and what is this feature, how does it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Can your provide some more context? What are these 2 results?

Comment: Yeah, the asterisk '*' indicates that the version is the chosen and active one. However, I see two asterisks in the output of `pyenv versions` command. Like this:
$ pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.18
* 3.9.4

Comment: Ohhh so you have python 2.7 installed, which, if you're on a Mac and some linux distros comes automatically. Don't worry about it, if it's a problem, just uninstall the 2.7 version

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you have 2 versions, 2.7 and 3.9. If you are on a Mac or  certain Linux distros, Python 2 comes preinstalled, which is why you would see it along with any other versions you installed (in this case 3.9).